# What is the different between $parent.find("children") vs $("children", $parent)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I know both the following statements will produce the same result,

```
 var $childNode = $parent.find("children"); and 
 var $childNode = $("children", $parent);
```

But I want to know which one is better to the other and why?

And how do these methods vary in implementation?

Comment: im just gonna venture a guess that it is just personal preference which one you use - I have never used the second one

Comment: It's up to you which one you use, the 2nd one is just a shorthand version of the first. As you said, they produce the same result.

Comment: *"Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so  $( "span", this ) is equivalent to  $( this ).find( "span" )."* - taken from [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/find/), there is no difference:

> [Selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) is implemented with the `.find()` method; therefore, `$( "li.item-ii" ).find( "li" )` is equivalent to `$( "li", "li.item-ii" )`.

Comment: There is a small difference, `.find()` will be slightly faster (talking about 0.0000001 ms here)